# creating object of js which is in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Suppose i have a web page (www.demo.com) and that web page has some js(javascript1.js, javascript2.js) files.

Now i created another web page (called "www.newwebage.com") and loaded www.demo.com in an iFrame.

Now iwant to use those methods in javascript1.js and javascript2.js in my newwebpage.com, so that don't have create another js file for the newwebpage.com, i use those methods directly.

I tried "document.getElementById('yourIFrame').contentWindow.yourFunction();" but didn't find it working.

Comment: Create a single shared .js file that you can load into both pages and use it that way.  This is the "right" way to solve this problem.  The file itself will be cached by the browser and only loaded over the network once.  You will not successfully share a .js file loaded into an iframe on another domain.  The browser's security settings will block you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its hard to achieve this, since your two websites don't come from the same origin.

*"The essence of the Same Origin policy can be formulated as: windows can work in contexts of each other only if they are from same protocol://domain:port, or, shortly, from same origin."*

http://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy

There are workarounds, namely the [cross-window messaging](http://javascript.info/tutorial/cross-window-messaging-with-postmessage), but you need to be in control of both domains. In essence, you would be fighting browsers that actively prohibit this, as it is considered a security flaw.

Comment: and suppose the domains and ports are same then its possible ?

Comment: yes, protocol must be the same as well, than the browser will allow the communication between iframes

Comment: that's my question, how?? i tried this "document.getElementById('yourIFrame').contentWindow.yourFunction();" but it's not working.

Comment: that's exactly how you should do it, if you like, paste a simplified HTML, to check it out